# Understanding this lyrics in "all of me" (John Legend)

Tags: lyrics

I do not see what is going on in this lyrics (John Legend, All of me). What does it mean "smart mouth", "pin you down", or "mystery ride"?  Also, the whole scene in the lyrics sounds like a sexual assault (that "pin you down" gives me that impression unfortunately), but I must have misunderstood the whole story. Any clarification?

```
What would I do without your smart mouth?
Drawing me in, and you kicking me out
You've got my head spinning, no kidding, I can't pin you down
What's going on in that beautiful mind?
I'm on your magical mystery ride
And I'm so dizzy, don't know what hit me, but I'll be alright
```

Comment: Hello, since song lyrics are open to interpretation (and often make little sense), we don't do that here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the whole scene in the lyrics sounds like a sexual assault (that "pin you down" gives me that impression unfortunately)

"Pin  down" has a metaphorical meaning of "understand ".

Given the next lyric ("What's going on ..."), I would expect that the writer intended this meaning rather than a literal one related to sexual activity (consensual or otherwise).

Comment: Thanks. Then what does "smart mouth" mean?

Comment: @zell, "smart mouth" is a well known idiom meaning speak disrespectfully. You should look up these basic definitions before posting a question on ELU.

Comment: Thanks! @The Photon.

Comment: It seems that "I'm on your magical mystery ride" is not an idiom. Could you help explain that?

Comment: @zell it’s probably meant as a reference to the Beatles song “Magical Mystery Tour”, but that’s a question of interpretation, not grammar. Interpretation of songs is off topic on this site.